# Timestamp or date column query issue cassandra 4 (astradb)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-cassandra, datastax-astra

I am facing issue with querying cassandra (astradb) from springboot aplication.

Here are the details I am using:

```
'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.8'

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra'



//cassandra specific driver
    implementation 'com.datastax.astra:astra-spring-boot-starter:0.3.0'
    implementation 'com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core:4.14.1'
    implementation 'com.datastax.oss:java-driver-query-builder:4.14.1'
    implementation 'com.datastax.oss:java-driver-mapper-runtime:4.14.1'
```

In order to retrieve data I am using Cassandra Java jpa.

Here is my Repository:

```
  @Query(value = "select * from engine_torque_by_last_date " +
            "where vin_number = :vinNumber " +
            "and organization_id in :organizationId and " +
            "stats_date = totimestamp(:dateString)")
    List<EngineTorqueByLastDate> findByVinNumberAndOrganizationIdAndStatsDate(String vinNumber, Integer organizationId, String dateString);
```

Now In Pojo I have defined Attribute as TimeStamp.

Below is the error:

```
{
  "title": "Internal Server Error",
  "status": 500,
  "detail": "Query; CQL [select * from engine_torque_by_last_date where vin_number = ? and organization_id in ? and stats_date = totimestamp(?)]; Ambiguous call to function totimestamp (can be matched by following signatures: system.totimestamp : (timeuuid) -> timestamp, system.totimestamp : (date) -> timestamp): use type casts to disambiguate; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.InvalidQueryException: Ambiguous call to function totimestamp (can be matched by following signatures: system.totimestamp : (timeuuid) -> timestamp, system.totimestamp : (date) -> timestamp): use type casts to disambiguate",
  "cause": {
    "title": "Internal Server Error",
    "status": 500,
    "detail": "Ambiguous call to function totimestamp (can be matched by following signatures: system.totimestamp : (timeuuid) -> timestamp, system.totimestamp : (date) -> timestamp): use type casts to disambiguate"
  }
}

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS autonostixdq.engine_torque_by_last_date (
                                                                       id UUID,
                                                                       engine_torque text,
                                                                       vin_number text,
                                                                       last_updated timestamp,
                                                                       organization_id int,
                                                                       odometer int,
                                                                       stats_date timestamp,
                                                                       miles double,
                                                                       hours double,
                                                                       engine_runtime int,
                                                                       key_starts int,
                                                                       threshold text,
                                                                       PRIMARY KEY ((vin_number, organization_id), stats_date, odometer));
```

api takes date as a string '2022-05-27' then tried both. Passing just a string '2022-05-27'. Tried with making it '2022-05-27 00:00:00.000000+0000'. Earlier I kept stats_date field as Date type in cassandra and tried passing LocalTime object.

How Do I resolve this problem ?

Comment: Could you please edit your question to show us the table schema. We would need the type of `stats_date` in the Cassandra table: Timestamp, Date, timeuuid. Based on this we could give you the syntax. Also is you can give us a sample value for `dateString`. My Intuition so far is you would have to convert `dateString` as Instant and no need any `totimestamp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the schema of the table `stats_date` is a timestamp.

Looking at Spring Data Cassandra Mapping [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-conversion)  a `java.util.Date` is the related Java Type for this CQL Type.

I suggest to convert the `dataString` parameter to a `java.util.Date` using the good old java class `SimpleDateFormat` in the java code before and change the repository code with the following:

```
@Query(value = "select * from engine_torque_by_last_date " +
        "where vin_number = :vinNumber " +
        "and organization_id in :organizationId and " +
        "stats_date = :dateString")
List<EngineTorqueByLastDate> findByVinNumberAndOrganizationIdAndStatsDate(String vinNumber, Integer organizationId, Date dateString);
```

You can probably totally get rid of `@Query`, it is a standard query and your should use the convention in Spring Data. Try to rename the function to :

`findByKeyVinNumberAndKeyOrganizationIdAndKeyStatsDate`

Comment: Thanks for the help @clunven .I actually tried that, and as per your suggestion I modified accordingly and re ran. However ran into this error: 
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.type.codec.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [List(INT, not frozen) <-> java.lang.Integer]

Comment: @TuhinSubhraMandal Not sure if you're still stuck on this or not, but I have seen the "Codec not found" before when the types specified in the Entity or PrimaryKey class don't match the underlying CQL table.